# How to exchange the data between property pages?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet where it does contain 4 pages.In the second page I am having a list control where it is getting enumerated by some values.In the third page I am having a listbox.whatever the value listcontrol is  getting enumerated of second page ,should get added to the listbox in the third page.
//DDX routine for second page listcontrol is as follows.

```
void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_MODEL, m_listCtrl);
}
```

//DDX routine for the third page lisbox is as follows.

```
void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_BOX, m_listBoxCtrl);
}
```

And in the second page OnWizardNext() I added the following code to assign the second page listcontrol values to the third page member variables.

```
LRESULT OnWizardNext()

{
  UpdateData(TRUE);
  int nListItemCount = m_listCtrl.GetItemCount();
  m_str = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(0,1);
  m_str1 = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(0,2);
  m_str2 = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(0,3);
  //assigning the second page data member values to the third page member variables.
  CConfirmationView dlg;//third page class
  dlg.m_szItemData.Format(L"  %s",m_str);
  dlg.m_szItemData1.Format(L"  %s",m_str1);
  dlg.m_szItemData2.Format(L"  %s",m_str2);
  UpdateData(FALSE);
  return CPropertyPage::OnWizardNext();
}
```

And in the third page OnInitDialog() I am added this piece of code to add the value that is retrieved from second page listcontrol to the third page listbox as follows.

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
  CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();
  Updatedata(FALSE);
  m_ListBoxCtrl.AddString(m_szItemData);
  m_ListBoxCtrl.AddString(m_szItemData1);
  m_ListBoxCtrl.AddString(m_szItemData2);
  return TRUE;
}
```

//Invoking wizard from InitInstance()

```
#include "firstpage.h"
#include "secondpage.h"
#include "thirdpage.h"
#include "fourthpage.h"
#include "myapp.h"
BOOL InitInstance()
{
CMyWizardSheet mysheet;
CFirstPage pg1;
CSecondPage pg2;
CThirdPage pg3;
CFourthPage pg4;
mysheeet.AddPage(&pg1);
mysheeet.AddPage(&pg2);
mysheeet.AddPage(&pg3);
mysheeet.AddPage(&pg4);
}
```

This is how I am doing.I want the item's data of the listcontrol(second page) to get added to the listbox (third page) . 
Can anyone please let me know how we can exchange the data between the pages.

Answer (score 0):

`CConfirmationView dlg;//third page class` will not work, you need the pointer to the ACTUAL instance of the dialog when it was created (normally in your app's `InitInstance()` method); you can store a pointer to the dialog as a member variable in your app class.

```
// add member variable in myapp class (myapp.h)
public:
CThirdPage *m_pThirdPage;
```

```
// in myapp InitInstance(), after all the AddPage() calls
m_pThirdPage = &pg3;
```

The second page's `OnWizardNext()` would then have logic like

```
//assigning the second page data member values to the third page member variables.
myapp *pApp = (myapp *) AfxGetApp();
pApp->m_pThirdPage->m_szItemData.Format(L"  %s",m_str);
pApp->m_pThirdPage->m_szItemData1.Format(L"  %s",m_str1);
pApp->m_pThirdPage->m_szItemData2.Format(L"  %s",m_str2);
```

Comment: I tried doing in the way you suggested.Then I am getting an error (Cbaseclass is undeclared base class)actually all of pages are derived from a base class called CbaseClass and this base class is derived from CPropertyPage.So Always it is indicating same error as Cbaseclass is undeclared base class in ConfirmationView.h file of CConfirmationView class ,the cursor is moving to this position in the header file.                                                   class CConfirmationView : public CInstallerBase
{//Here is place it is indicating error.I even added the header file(Checked twice)

Comment: could you edit the question and add code showing how you invoke the wizard and from where?

Comment: Please find the change in the code at the end I added the code where I was invoking the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer to your `CProperySheet` to each of your `CPropertyPages` via the constructor (this) so you have access to all the ohter pages defined in the parent sheet, then declare the pages as friend class to the other pages of concern so you can access the desired members and call their `UpdateData()`.